# Ubuntu giving permissions from java

Tags: java, ubuntu, file-permissions

This is one of a few Bash scripts I create in my pipeline. My Difficulty is I would like to make the created file executable without the user having to enter into the terminal "sudo chmod 777 /file/path/"

```
String Trans_ref = 
    "#!/bin/bash \n" +
    "mkdir -p "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM \n" +
    "cd "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM \n" +
    "PATH=$PATH:"+RSEMprep+" \n" +
    "export PATH=$PATH \n" + 
    ""+RSEMprep+"/rsem-prepare-reference --no-polyA --bowtie "+Output+"/Trans_CDHIT.fast Trans_CDHIT.RSEM \n" +    
    ""+RSEMprep+"/rsem-calculate-expression --paired-end -p "+CPU+" "+Output+"/SRR617145_1.fastq "+Output+"/SRR617145_2.fastq Trans_CDHIT.RSEM Trans_CDHIT.genes.results  \n"+
    ""+Trinprep+"/util/misc/count_features_given_MIN_FPKM_threshold.pl "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM/RSEM.genes.results > "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM/cumul_counts.txt \n"+
    ""+Trinprep+"/util/filter_fasta_by_rsem_values.pl --rsem_output= "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM/RSEM.isoforms.results --fasta="+Output+"/Trans_CDHIT.fasta -t 100 --output="+Output+"/"+Sample+"_RSEM/Trans_RSEMfilters.fasta \n" +
    ""+Trinprep+"/util/bowtie_PE_separate_then_join.pl --seqType fq --left "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_1.fasta --right "+Output+"/"+Sample+"_2.fasta --target "+Output+"/Trans_CDHIT.fasta --aligner bowtie --SS_lib_type FR -- -p 4 --all --best --strata -m 300 \n";  


        System.out.println(Trans_ref);

        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(Output+"/TranRSEM"), Trans_ref);
        StringBuffer Trim = new StringBuffer();

        String cmd = (Output+"/TranRSEM");


    Process p;

    try{
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c", cmd});

        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader1 = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("Merg Finished");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


        }
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways, but the best would be to use [SetExecutable](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javadoc.html#setExecutable(java.lang.String))
once you created the file. It would look something like this.

```
 if (file.exists()) {
            boolean bval = file.setExecutable(true);
            ..... set the owner's execute permission
        } else {
            ...... File does not exist;
        }


 if (file.exists()) {
            boolean bval = file.setExecutable(true, false);
            ..... set everybody's execute permission
        } else {
            ...... File does not exist;
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This was just the kind of thing i needed worked a charm